# html id and class for js and css in same component not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am enabling and disabling a div by checking two radio button (yes and no) but I am facing an issue when I am putting both id and class in same div and when I am using two div (one for id as parent and another for class as child) then its working fine.

```js
function check1() {
  if (document.getElementById("isOutsourcing_yes").checked) {
    document.getElementById("s1").hidden = false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("isOutsourcing_no").checked) {
    document.getElementById("s1").hidden = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.padd_left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="isOutsourcing" id="isOutsourcing_yes" onchange="check1()" checked> Yes
<input type="radio" name="isOutsourcing" id="isOutsourcing_no" onchange="check1()"> No
    
<div id="s1" class="padd_left">
    <h1>Hello..</h1>
</div>
```

above code is not working but when I am replacing last div as below then it's working fine

```
<div  class="padd_left">
    <div id="s1">
        <h1>Hello..</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline blocks aren't a big fan of hidden. Try this instead

```
document.getElementById("s1").style.visibility = "hidden"; // or visible
```

Also note the difference between the `display` property and the `visibility` property. You could set it to `display: none` if you wanted it to completely disappear from the page without a trace (besides in the source). `visibility: hidden` will have it take up the same space but not render anything. Depending on how you want your page to look, you'll have to make that decision.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: that is if we toggle `display` property, here OP uses [`hidden` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)...

Comment: oops, sorry I misread the question... you are right! upvoted :)

Comment: Yeah, my point was to replace the hidden toggle with a style change. Admittedly, the link I had before wasn't referencing hidden directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the more simple solution using only pure CSS and HTML, without javascript

```css
.padd_left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

#isOutsourcing_no:checked + #s1 h1{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="isOutsourcing" id="isOutsourcing_yes" checked> Yes
<input type="radio" name="isOutsourcing" id="isOutsourcing_no"> No
    
<div id="s1" class="padd_left">
    <h1>Hello..</h1>
</div>
```